# Query Oracle Database On Who Has Create Database Link Privs (private)?

Tags: permissions, dblink

Anybody know a good way to query the entire Oracle database on what users have privs to make private database links? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find them by querying the dba_sys_privs view.

Comment: Thank you it worked well.